# database group by need all other columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables -

1. chapter
2. lecture

Chapter table

```
 chapter_id | chapter_title
```

Lecture table

```
 lecture_id | chapter_id | lecture_title | lecture_content
```

My question is - I insert chapters for that chapter it have multiple lectures. So it follow for each chapters.
now I need to select single chapter title and with multiple lecture title and lecture content .

```
     SELECT * FROM `course_chapter`
 INNER JOIN course_lecture 
         ON course_lecture.chapter_id= course_chapter.chapter_id 
      WHERE course_chapter.course_id=1
```

I used above query my same chapter shows in many rows based on lecture available so need query for single chapter title and mulitiple lectures. how to do it?

Comment: I think you have multiple `chapters` for the `courses` or for `course_id` 1 ??

Comment: yes i have muiltiple chapter for course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want all lecture title and lecture content in a single row followed by  chapter title? If it is then you can try with this query

```
SELECT
  course_chapter.chapter_title,
  tmp.lecture_title,
  tmp.lecture_content
FROM course_chapter
  JOIN (SELECT
          chapter_id,
          GROUP_CONCAT(lecture_title SEPARATOR ', ')    'lecture_title',
          GROUP_CONCAT(lecture_content SEPARATOR ', ')    'lecture_content'
        FROM course_lecture
        GROUP BY chapter_id) tmp
    ON (tmp.chapter_id = course_chapter.chapter_id)
WHERE course_chapter.chapter_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use right join for this

Try the following

```
SELECT course_lecture.chapter_id, course_chapter.chapter_id, course_lecture.lecture_id, course_lecture.chapter_id, course_lecture.lecture_title, course_lecture.lecture_content FROM `course_chapter` right join course_lecture on course_lecture.chapter_id=course_chapter.chapter_id WHERE course_chapter.chapter_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you wanted to add a condition on `where` clause on `chapter_id` not `course_id` because each `course` can have multiple `chapters` so replace the condition as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `course_chapter`
INNER JOIN course_lecture ON course_lecture.chapter_id= course_chapter.chapter_id 
WHERE course_chapter.chapter_id = 1
```

You can also add condition on `course_id` if you want to return `chapter` from particular course. Just add `AND course_chapter.course_id = <desired_id>`